# How to see changes happening to my HTML by a jQuery script?

Tags: jquery, html, debugging

What is the best way to see the changes happening to my HTML while something is changed with AJAX / jQuery? The change happens too quickly (and disappears afterwards) for me to properly debug the HTML added through Firebug.

Edit: I did not write the script itself and have no control over it either.

Comment: Note: This is my first stackoverflow question. I couldn't find a solution to this with Google or searches on here, so I'm sorry if this is super obvious.

Comment: If you insert an alert you block execution. Add console.log to see stuff without alerting. Inspect element and add a breakpoint and step the execution to really see what is going on

Comment: I should have noted that I didn't write the script, it's a Drupal-internal AJAX response that's inserted into the page. Will add that to the question.

Comment: Just to add to mplugnaj's suggestion, you can track all the communication between browser and server using Firefox with Firebug. Yes, there will be a lot of information that you don't need, but it is a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that this will help you or not, but you should run it in FF & use the FF addons like Firebug & Venkman (Javascript Debugger) for debbugging HTML & JS.

You will be able to see the HTML dynamic changes in the Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome developer tool you can select DOM-element, and put DOM-breakpoint `Subtree modification`. After that, if some script tries to change it, debugger will break at this point in code. Don't know about other developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log('usual info log');
console.warn('warning will show exclam. mark in FF or yellow color text in Opera');
console.error('you will definitely recognize it from all the rest');
```

These few functions should help you to distinguish what is happening during the runtime if you are planning to watch your workflow using your logs.

Regarding structure changes, as was mentioned several times above, you can watch your DOM using breakpoints.